# King Composer - add multiple JS file for Google Map Field

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I need to add multiple JS file in using king composer. 
I follow [Add Map](http://docs.kingcomposer.com/?s=assets)
but could not load multiple files.

Code is use for WordPress theme option for show map on selection page.

```
<?php
$kc->add_map(array(
    'location' => array(
        'name' => 'Locations',
        'description' => 'Add your location details',
        'icon' => 'cpicon kc-icon-map',
        'category' => 'Content',
        'assets' => array(
            'scripts' => array(
                'googlemap_js' => "MY JS FILE PATH",
                'type' => 'javascript',
                'jquery' => '',
            ) ,
            'scripts' => array(
                'location_js' => 'MY JS FILE PATH',
                'type' => 'javascript',
                'jquery' => '',
            ) ,
        ) ,
        'params' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'image',
                'label' => 'Upload Images',
                'type' => 'attach_images',
                'admin_label' => true,
            ) ,
        )
    ) ,
));
?>
```

Comment: And the error is...? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MaciejJureczko I didn't got any error but load only one JS fine, is there missing from my side?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong ways to add the scripts;

It must be

```
    <?php
$kc->add_map(array(
    'location' => array(
        'name' => 'Locations',
        'description' => 'Add your location details',
        'icon' => 'cpicon kc-icon-map',
        'category' => 'Content',
        'assets' => array(
            'scripts' => array(
                'googlemap_js' => "MY JS FILE PATH",
                'location_js' => 'MY JS FILE PATH',
                'js_lib1' => 'MY JS FILE PATH',
                'js_lib2' => 'MY JS FILE PATH',
                'jquery' => '', //calling the script enqueue before - enqueue from other place.
            ) ,
        ) ,
        'params' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'image',
                'label' => 'Upload Images',
                'type' => 'attach_images',
                'admin_label' => true,
            ) ,
        )
    ) ,
));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll check. :)